# Как транслировать изображение с экрана PC на экран Android(Android SDK)

Tags: java, android, share, display

Хочу создать приложение для VR Cardboard,которое будет транслировать экран PC на телефон и разделять его на два для VR очков. Собственно вопрос заключаеться как транслировать(передавать) изображение с ПК на телефон через провод USB. Маленкий дополнительный вопрос на будущее как улучшить качество предачи данных.

Answer (score 0):

Без деталей реализации, могу предположить следующее:

- Нужно с помощью ОС получать поток видео, закодировать в формат, который андроид нативно сможет декодировать, разделить видео на 2 со смещением (не в курсе тонкостей VR, нужно изучать вопрос как это делают Valve, HTC и тп), который направлять на usb
- На мобиле открыть usb устройство через USBManager
- Написать логику для TextureView в который выводить собственно видеопоток